# Accessing array inside of object from inside the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've done similar things before but I can't get this to work.

I run this and get "Cannot read property '0' or undefined..."

(The randomResult() function returns a random element from a passed array and works ok elsewhere.)

```
var objectOfArrays = {
  array1: ["apple","orange","pear","mango"],
  array2: [
    "I want no fruit!",
    "I will have one " + randomResult(this.array1) + "."
  ]
}

console.log(randomResult(objectOfArrays.array2));
```

Comment: where is your `randomResult` function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is not defined yet, you can't use `this` inside an object declaration.

To be clear, something like that:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: this.a,
  c: obj.a
}
```

Won't work, both `b` and `c` cannot access to the object that is *currently* declared.

However, if you *delay* the access, then it will works:

```
const objectOfArrays = {
  array1: ["apple","orange","pear","mango"],
  get array2() {
    return [
      "I want no fruit!",
      "I will have one " + randomResult(this.array1) + "."
    ]
  }
}
```

Defining a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) the code will be executed only when you're trying to access to `objectOfArrays.array2`. Keep in mind two things, however: first, it will be readonly: if you want to set also the prop `array2` you have to create a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) too. Second, and more important, in this way, *every time* you access to `array2` the getter is executed, therefore a new array is returned – with a new random result from `array1`. If you want to return the same, you have to cache the result somewhere:

```
const objectOfArrays = {
  array1: ["apple","orange","pear","mango"],
  _array2: null, // this could be actually omitted, see `Symbol` example
  get array2() {
    return this._array2 || (this._array2 = [
      "I want no fruit!",
      "I will have one " + randomResult(this.array1) + "."
    ])
  }
}
```

<s>(You could use `Symbol` for make the property more private, but it's better not over complicate things now)</s>

**Using Symbol**

Since it was asked in the comment, *even if it's outside the scope of the answer*.

Caching the property to `_array2` is good enough in most of the cases; however the property is easily accessible directly:

```
console.log(objectOfArrays._array2) // null
```

And can be tampered easily:

```
objectOfArrays._array2 = [1, 2];
```

Changing the behavior of the getter in `array2`.

A Symbol could be used to make `_array2` more private. Assuming we are in a module:

```
const _array2 = Symbol("array2"); // the string is just for debug

export default objectOfArrays = {
  array1: ["apple","orange","pear","mango"],
  get array2() {
    return this[_array2] || (this[_array2] = [
      "I want no fruit!",
      "I will have one " + randomResult(this.array1) + "."
    ])
  }
}
```

In this way, outside the module there is no a direct way to refer the "private" `_array2` property, since the Symbol is needed – and we do not export that.
It won't also appear in iteration (for example, with `Object.keys(objectOfArrays)`). Of course there is still a way to access to it, using [getOwnPropertySymbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols), but that means usually a more deliberate code than an accident one – e.g. iterate the keys of an object.

I mentioned module, but this is also applying if we're using a block scope:

```
 // create a block
 {
   // const is block scoped, therefore is not accessible outside
   const _array2 = Symbol("array2");

   // `var` is not block scoped, so it will be accessible outside
   // also `global.objectOfArrays` would be valid, where `global`
   // is a reference to the global object (there is a spec to have
   // it by default but is not implemented yet.
   var objectOfArrays = ... // same code
 }
```

Or in a closure:

```
 (function(exports) {
   const _array2 = Symbol("array2");

   exports.objectOfArrays = ... // same code
 }(this)); // or `window` or whatever is the export object / global one.
```

Comment: Great answer. But I'm curious: how could you use `Symbol`s here?

Comment: this refers to the window object or global if there is no binding context.

Comment: Thanks Zero.  That clears it up.  I was not familiar with getter but suddenly see some potential application for it.  I'll read up on it.  Lots of good stuff here.

Comment: I added a section about how to use `Symbol`. I believe it's outside the scope of your question, but it could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative can be temporary variable:

```js
var temp, objectOfArrays = {
  array1: temp = ["apple","orange","pear","mango"],
  array2: [
    "I want no fruit!",
    "I will have one " + temp + "."
  ]
}

console.log( objectOfArrays );
```

or separate statements:

```js
var objectOfArrays = { array1: temp = ["apple","orange","pear","mango"] };

objectOfArrays.array2 = [ "I want no fruit!",
    "I will have one " + objectOfArrays.array1 + "." ];

console.log( objectOfArrays );
```